# Asymmetrical Border Image in CSS

Tags: css

How would one create the following 'paintbrush' effect as a border around a div in CSS? The div in this case would be the red box.

[image]

Here is another example of a similar situation. The div in this case would be the blue box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your best bet is to go with the `border-image` property

You can find some more info/examples here http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ You just need to find the stroke effect that you like and apply it in your case to the `border-image`

Heres a example

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/EVgaQL